# Problema al cambiar color de fondo cuando pase le mouse sobre ella

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un problema en javascript con la etiqueta div quiero cambiarle el color de fondo cuando pase le mause sobre ella pero no cambia de color

Esto llevo vi un ejemplo en el  que se declaraba  una función con 2 parámetros

```
function color(n,r){
if(r=='si')
    document.getElementById(n).style.background="#FFOOCC"

else
    document.getElementById(n).style.background=""
```

y asi queda en la etiqueta div

```
<div id='1' onMouseOver=color('1','si') onMouseOut=color('1','n')>provando div1</div>
```

y no se cual es el problema
gracias

Comment: y porque no usar solo css y olvidar JS?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intercalar entre los eventos de  **mouseover** Y **mouseout** del mouse para realizar el cambio de colores de tu div.

```
<div id='n' onMouseOver=mouseOver() onMouseOut=mouseOut()>probando div1</div>

function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("n").style.color = "#FFOOCC";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("n").style.color = "black";
}
```

[onmouseover Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)

Igualo lo puedes hacer con CSS

```
#n:hover { 
    background-color: #FFOOCC;
}
```

Ahora aplicando tu función de dos parámetros puedes validar de esta forma

```js
function color(r){ 
    if(r=="si")
        document.getElementById('n').style.background ="blue"
    else 
        document.getElementById('n').style.background ="#f3f3f3"
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="n" onMouseOver=color('si') onMouseOut=color('n')>probando div1</div>
```

Comment: entonces lo que tengo de mi codigo lo dejo o lo quito por el nuevo que me brindaste

Comment: Edite, Lo ultimo utiliza la función que pediste. Dime ¿cual se adapta más a lo que necesitas?

Comment: no tengo que poner nada en la div como lo mostre en mi ejmplos

Comment: aun no funciona no muestra ningún color

Comment: No sé que tiene ese color en específico que no lo cambia, pero con cualquier otro si lo hace

Answer (score 1):

Tu error es el siguiente: el código lo color lo tienes erróneo, debes tener en cuenta que un código de color hexadecimal tiene 6 dígitos, que van de `A` a `F` y de `0` a `9`. En este caso en tu color estás pasando dos letras **o** mayúsculas (OO) lo cual no genera ningún color, simplemente cambia esas dos letras **o** por dos ceros (00), quedando así:

```js
function color(n,r){
  if(r=='si')
    document.getElementById(n).style.background="#FF00CC"
  else
    document.getElementById(n).style.background=""
}
```

```html
<div id='1' onMouseOver=color('1','si') onMouseOut=color('1','n')>provando div1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Su problema es que `#FFOOCC` lo tiene como la letra 'O', pero debe de ser el numero '0'

Como alternativa, tambien lo puede hacer solo con `CSS` así:

```css
#div1:hover{
  background-color: #FF00CC;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>provando div1</div>
```